# From the existence of the limit of derivatives we can conclude the differentiability.

Tags: derivatives

it should actually be quite easy but i have difficulties to prove this fact: if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous everewhere and is differentiable everywhere except for $x_0$ and if $\lim_{x\to x_0}f^{'}(x)$ exists, then $f^{'}(x_0)$ exists.
Could someone help please?
Thanks.

Comment: It follows from L'Hospital's rule, alternatively look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3989133/question-about-differentiability-at-a-point/3989151#3989151).

Comment: thanks a lot!!!